# Joins vs more columns

Tags: android, performance, sqlite, inner-join

I plan to have up to 50000 items in an SQLite database for my Android app. I am considering breaking up a 15 column table to remove redundancy. I thought joining three separate tables would be more inefficient on a low power device (Android 2.1 devices) than storing redundant data and indexing it properly.

Does anyone have experience or resources for Android? I found nothing about redundant data vs triple inner-joins. Most of the queries will need to do a double inner-join at least if I break it up properly. Any data needed that can help explain this more?

Comment: Your table schema would help, along with your expectation of which fields would be searched-on most often. Joins are not always going to be more expensive than a query against a flattened|denormalized table. Main goal is to avoid disk-bound operations. An index on repetitive text values, which could have been normalized using integer foreign keys, might involve more disk i/o than would a join on those integer values.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of it does depend on your table scheme however I understand you may not be able to post that here. I would personally go with breaking the table up into multiple tables instead of having one table with a lot of redundant data.  I've done something similar and actually saw faster queries.  Also, the speed of phones are increasing dramatically so its really worth having a cleaner database structure.